# Brunch.io brunch-config.js semantic of order.before:

Tags: javascript, configuration-files, brunch

lets consider the following entry in a brunch-config.js:

```
    joinTo: {
          "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
          "js/vendor.js": /^(web\/static\/vendor)|(deps)/
          },

   order: {
         before: [
           "web/static/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
         ]
       }
```

Clearly during concatenation "jquery.min.js" will be put before.

Question 1: ... put before WHAT file - app.js or vendor.js or both?

Question 2: Are the patterns in joinTo e.g. /^(web/static/vendor)|(deps)/  recursive, meaning are all subpath are included in the search for *.js files?

Answer (score 2):

`order.before` basically means the ordering of files inside the concatenated output.

In your case, the jquery file would be the first file inside `js/vendor.js` output. It would not create its own output file.

Patterns inside `joinTo` are recursive — but beware, Brunch does not watch *all* directories per se. Brunch uses paths from `config.paths.watched` (in your case it may include `web/static` and `deps` directories).